# linux alternative for google-voice-typing

Tags: linux, voice-command, voice-recognition

I am looking for a linux alternative for google-voice-typing. I came across mycroft which is actually a assistant.I am looking for much more minimal one. I just need the type words through voice while writing a document,or do a command on bash. While I used GSConect it didn't work correctly rather printed a single character and all remaining spaces.I am on Gnome in fedora32.

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for a voice-typing alternative. I came across these two:

- [Mozilla's DeepSpeach](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech), with relative [documentation](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/r0.9/?badge=latest)
- [Nerd Dictation](https://github.com/ideasman42/nerd-dictation), a Python wrapper around the [VOSK-API](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api). Here is a [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7sR-4DFhpQ).

Both of them work via Python, and are easily installed.

### Nerd Dictation

Personally, I have experience with the second, that served me quite well, both for Italian and English.

The workflow is as follows. You need to install the package **and** the pretrained model for the language you want to type in. Then, having a mic plugged-in, you spawn a terminal and run the command

```
nerd-dictation begin
```

Now, your speech input will be processed and inserted wherever you are typing.
You need to manually stop the process issuing

```
nerd-dictation end
```

The command also accepts optional parameters and you can configure the default language model to be used. The documentation on the GitHub page will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Numen](https://numenvoice.com), which is a system-wide keyboard alternative for Linux.

Comment: Welcome to SR.  Please edit your answer and improve it by providing more information.  And please declare your affiliation.  It is a little suspicious when both your answers are the same.

Comment: It won't let me edit it just now but this paste has what I'll say when I can:  https://paste.sr.ht/blob/d5fcb175f326d8ca1e17fa2af093b36f090b0808

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Still won't let me edit it. I'll try again in two days.

Comment: Looks like I've been blacklisted. I'm just going to delete my account.